# How to add text to multiple images using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, python-imaging-library

I am new to using Python and I have a problem that I can not solve. What I am trying to do is that from an excel spreadsheet that contains three columns (address of the image, text 1, and text 2 respectively), the code should select the first image and then insert text 1 and 2 that belongs to its row. I was able to complete the code for a single image, but I encounter a problem when I try to process all the images.

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

ruta_excel = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/san_2/Documents/Script/ARCPY/Direc.xls',
                           sheet_name=0)
ruta = ruta_excel.iat[0, 0]

image_files = Image.open(ruta)
font_type = ImageFont.truetype('C:/Windows.old/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf',18)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_files)
draw.text(xy=(20, 550), text=ruta_excel.iat[0, 1], fill=(255, 255, 255),
          font=font_type)
draw.text(xy=(20, 570), text=ruta_excel.iat[0, 2], fill=(255, 255, 255),
          font=font_type)

image_files.save(ruta, 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Thank you

Comment: I believe I have a solution for you, but because I have not used the `panadas` module before, I would just like to confirm one thing, does the line `ruta=ruta_excel.iat[0,0]`, mean look at first row and first column, of the excel file?, would that mean to look at the next row, it needs to be `ruta=ruta_excel.iat[1,0]`. This will help me ensure my answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `PIL` but if your code works for the first image and your problem is the iteration, then you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

ruta_excel=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/san_2/Documents/Script/ARCPY/Direc.xls',sheet_name=0)
# iterate over rows with itertuples
for row in ruta_excel.itertuples(index=False):
    print (row) # to help you see what is happening but not necessary after
    # row is tuple, doing row[0] access to the first item (the first column)
    ruta=row[0]
    image_files = Image.open(ruta)
    font_type = ImageFont.truetype('C:/Windows.old/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf',18)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_files)
    # here you use row[1] and row[2]
    draw.text(xy=(20,550),text= row[1],fill=(255,255,255),font=font_type)
    draw.text(xy=(20,570),text= row[2],fill=(255,255,255),font=font_type)

    image_files.save(ruta, 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked correctly and now I understand a bit more about the function for.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to loop over the items found by `pd.read_excel`. This function returns a `DataFrame` so you can use one of its three built-in iterators: [itertuples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), [iteritems](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) or [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

Given this example XLS:

```
|   | A              | B            | C             |
| - | -------------- |--------------| --------------|
| 1 | /a/file/path/1 | first text 1 | second text 1 |
| 2 | /a/file/path/2 | first text 2 | second text 2 |
| 3 | /a/file/path/3 | first text 3 | second text 3 |
| 4 | /a/file/path/4 | first text 4 | second text 4 |
| 5 | /a/file/path/5 | first text 5 | second text 5 |
```

When reading the file with pandas and you have no header row in the XLS, you should specify `header=None` and provide the column names within `names`. If you have a header row and it is the first row of the XLS, just pass `header=0` and omit `names`. By ensuring that you can map each column to a column name, you can work with `itertuples` which for your usecase is the best suited method - you can access the row values by their column names within the loop:

```
import pandas as pd

exc = pd.read_excel('file_text_map.xlsx', header=None, names=('file_path', 'text1', 'text2',))

for row in exc.itertuples(index=False):
  print('file_path:', row.file_path, ', text1:', row.text1, ', text2:', row.text2)
```

Which will result in

```
file_path: /a/file/path/1 , text1: first text 1 , text2: second text 1
file_path: /a/file/path/2 , text1: first text 2 , text2: second text 2
file_path: /a/file/path/3 , text1: first text 3 , text2: second text 3
file_path: /a/file/path/4 , text1: first text 4 , text2: second text 4
file_path: /a/file/path/5 , text1: first text 5 , text2: second text 5
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'll keep it in mind for the next scrip